# Moved QGIS 3.6 to new PC and now need to change Output folder and Scripts folder

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, migration

I moved my old QGIS to a new PC. Installed from zero, and later just copied "C:\Users[User]\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles". Everything works fine, when I open my old projects it's all the same - GREAT!

But, now, the problem is that one of the plugins (QGIS Resource Sharing) is not working because of a script error. My old profile name was "Filip", and new one is "Angry Stoic". I tried to change it in Settings>Options>Processing, but get this error:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of Processing. Tried to reinstall the plugin, but same error:
[image]

When opening the project I get the following error:

> WARNING    Python error : Couldn't load plugin 'qgis_resource_sharing'
> due to an error when calling its classFactory() method See message log
> (Python Error) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove all the "*Generated" custom CRS (in Settings -> Custom Projections... or Settings -> Options... -> User Defined CRS) in order to save the settings without errors.